# Case insensitive CSV query in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have data set for animal collisions on Virginia Roads. I'm trying to extract all the collisions that involved bears. In my data set, bear is typed with at least three different case combinations (i.e., Bear, bear, BEAR). The following is the code I'm using to extract bear collisions:

```
import csv

with open('google.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = [ row for row in reader if "bear" in row[4] ]

with open('outfile.csv', "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

How can I make this case-insensitive?

Comment: You could just convert the whole CSV file to lower case. If that's not suitable, then you can do this sort of thing: `[row for row in reader if "bear" in row[4].lower()]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('google.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = [ row for row in reader if "bear" in row[4].strip().lower() ]

with open('outfile.csv', "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```